# Htaccess 301 redirect from one directory to its subdirectory and keeping the main directory url accesible

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all pages coming under

- /directory/any-page

to

- /directory/supplier/any-page/

and what to keep the directory url accessible as the directory url also contain content which I need to display and i used this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule  ^/directory/(.*)$ /directory/supplier/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the leading slash from rewrite pattern, you will be fine

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory/supplier/
RewriteRule ^directory/(.+)$ /directory/supplier/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Hello Starkeen tried that too but it still didn't worked for me 
and http://festivalbrides.co.uk/directory/ url needs to be accessible

Comment: @EpicWebSolutions  added conditions to exclude your real files and folder from the rule

Comment: ok i used the code but its generating this
http://festivalbrides.co.uk/directory/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/supplier/beauty/

Comment: You are getting a redirect loop.Clear your browser cache and Try the updated rule now